# Python - matplotlib autoincrement save figure option

Tags: python, matplotlib, save

I have a silly - but very annoying - matplotlib question.  I constantly generate figures and save them to disk using the save button on the matplotlib pop-up figure display.  The default behaviour of that window used to auto-increment the index of the default name for the file to be saved, e.g. the option would be to save "Figure_120.png" when there were already 119 other figures saved.

But latest version of matplotlib doesn't do this by default and I have to edit and rename figures every time I do this.  Am I doing something wrong?  And how was matplotlib always reading the content of the default output directory to know how to index the default value?

[image]

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong. This was deliberately changed in [PR #10864](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/10864). Feel free to complain in this thread about it.

Comment: If I understand correctly what is written [here](https://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#don-t-automatically-rename-duplicate-file-names), the default name is now guessed using the figure canvas title (using `figure.Figure.canvas.set_window_title()`), so maybe a workaround would be to set this in the code before callings `show()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can save Figure in a directory.
 Directory will be renamed by the current date and figure with current time.
 Corresponding code:

```
import os.path
import os, errno

cur_Date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
cur_Time = time.strftime("%H-%M")
%create directory if it did not exist
try:
    os.makedirs(cur_Date)
except OSError as e:
    if e.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise
   # your figure creation lines ....
   # save the figure to file
   fig.savefig(cur_Time+'.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

So Thomas Kuhn's suggestion is a bit hacky - but it works: when you click on save box - it will save the figure as in title.  I added a random number, here's the full solution:

```
figure = plt.figure()
figure.canvas.set_window_title("Fig_"+str(np.random.randint(1E8)))
```